# Issue when configuring Hangfire in ASP.NET app

Tags: hangfire

I'm attempting to wire up Hangfire in my ASP.NET application (not Core) using the Global.asax.cs route explained [in their documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-applications.html). However, none of their extensions methods on GlobalConfiguration.Configuration seem to be working for me. It appears, for one example, that `SetDataCompatibiltyLevel()` method extends `Hangfire.IGlobalConfiguration`, which my `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` does not inherit from. I even backed off a few versions of Hangfire and it doesn't seem to make a difference. When I attempt to access the extensions method directly, I get this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix `GlobalConfiguration` class with the `Hangfire` namespace – `System.Web.Http` namespace defines its own `GlobalConfiguration` class, so you get a conflict. And that another class is referenced, most likely because you have the `System.Web.Http` namespace included in the beginning of the file.

```cs
Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibiltyLevel.Version_170);
```

You can also combine all the calls to the `GlobalConfiguration` class in a single chain:

```cs
Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibiltyLevel.Version_170)
    .UseXXX()
    .UseYYYStorage();
```